# Save netCDF file to grib file

Tags: python, netcdf, grib, pygrib

I am trying to save a netCDF file to a grib file, but I get several error with trying different things.

First when I load the netcdf file in Iris I get the `FutureWarning: Ignoring a datum in netCDF load for consistency with existing behaviour. In a future version of Iris, this datum will be applied. To apply the datum when loading, use the iris.FUTURE.datum_support flag. cubes = iris.load(data_path + file)` error

It does load the cube, so blindly ignorant I continue and try to save the file with `iris.save` or `iris_grib.save_grib2`:

```
import iris
import iris.plot as iplt
import iris.quickplot as qplt
import iris_grib
import xarray as xr
import cfgrib
import xarray as xr
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cubes = iris.load(data_path + file)

iris_grib.save_grib2(cubes[0], data_path+'test.grib2')
```

or

```
iris.save(cubes[0],data_path+'test.grib2')
```

But I get the error:
`TranslationError: time coord not found`

I have tried downloading the file in xarray, then converting it to a cube and then save it as grib. But this gives the error: 'TranslationError: CoordSystem not present'

```
cubie = ds.z.to_iris()

iris_grib.save_grib2(cubie, data_path+'test.grib2')
```

I have tried, making a netcdf of my data, and downloading the file in xarray and then converting it to a cube, but this gives the error `ValueError: substring not found`

```
DS = xr.Dataset({
'SIC' : xr.DataArray(
data = [ds.z.values],
dims = ['time','projection_y_coordinate','projection_x_coordinate'],
coords = {'time':times,'projection_x_coordinate':ds.x.values,'projection_y_coordinate':ds.y.values},
attrs = { 'units':'%','author':ds.author,'GMT_version':ds.GMT_version,\
         'history':ds.history,'info':ds.info,'title':ds.title,'GDAL':ds.GDAL}),})

DS.SIC.to_iris()
```

I then tried to just add the time coordinate to my original cube:

```
Time= iris.coords.DimCoord(times, long_name='time')
cubes.add_dim_coord(Time, 0)
```

but this does not work because: `CannotAddError: A dim_coord is already associated with dimension 1.` so I tried with `dim = 0`, and `dim = 2`, but that does not work because `CannotAddError: The cube does not have the specified dimension (2)`

I feel I have run out of options and would love to have your help!

you can freely download the data: [Remote sensing Antarctica Bremen](https://data.seaice.uni-bremen.de/databrowser/#day=9&month=1&year=2024&img=%7B%22image%22%3A%22image-1%22%2C%22product%22%3A%22AMSR%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22visual%22%2C%22region%22%3A%22Antarctic%22%7D)